# How do I convert a Tibble to HTML Table in R tidyverse?

Tags: html, r, html-table, tibble

I'm wanting a way to convert the results of a pipeline manipulation into a table so it can be rendered as a HTML table in **R** Markdown.

Sample data:

```
Category <- sample(1:6, 394400) 
Category <- sample(1:6, 394400, replace=TRUE)
Category <- factor(Category,
                    levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                    labels = c("First",
                               "Second",
                               "Third",
                               "Fourth",
                               "Fifth",
                               "Sixth"))
data <- data.frame(Category)
```

Then I build a frequency table using the pipeline:

```
Table <- data %>%
             group_by(Category) %>%
             summarise(N= n(), Percent = n()/NROW(data)*100) %>%
             mutate(C.Percent = cumsum(Percent))
```

Which gives me this nice little summary table here:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Category     N  Percent C.Percent
    <fctr> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1    First 65853 16.69701  16.69701
2   Second 66208 16.78702  33.48403
3    Third 65730 16.66582  50.14985
4   Fourth 65480 16.60243  66.75228
5    Fifth 65674 16.65162  83.40390
6    Sixth 65455 16.59610 100.00000
```

However if I try to convert that to a table to then convert to HTML, it tells me it cannot coerce `Table` to a table. This is the same with data frames as well.

Does anyone know a way, as I'd quite like to customise the appearance of the output?

Comment: You don't describe how you tried to "convert that to a table to then convert to HTML." Maybe `knitr::kable` from will work for you?

Comment: Use the `DT` package to create a [data table](http://rstudio.github.io/DT). I use it all the time and it is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There are several packages for that. Here are some:

```
knitr::kable(Table)

htmlTable::htmlTable(Table)

ztable::ztable(as.data.frame(Table))

DT::datatable(Table)

stargazer::stargazer(Table, type = "html")
```

Each of these has different customization options.

Comment: kable worked a treat for that one, I also have some more complex tables though that are built with formulas using the "tables" package. Do you know if there's a way to get kable to work with them too?

Comment: If you wrap that `tables` object in `html()` the output is an html table

Comment: If you want to use `kable` specifically, you can do something like `kable(as.matrix(complex_table))`. You'll probably have to edit the resulting rmarkdown though.

Comment: @Nick for complex tables, you can check out [kableExtra](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/)

Comment: That's brilliant Hao! Thanks!